# Share link using whatsapp

Tags: ios, objective-c, whatsapp

I used these code for share app link in what's app but nothing is come in the textfield of whatsapp. If using simple text then its work. Can anyone suggest the final outcome.

```
NSString *theTempMessage = @"whatsapp://send?text=https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/myapp/id1054375332?ls=1&mt=8";
NSString *theFinalMessage;

theTempMessage = [theTempMessage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"%3A"];
theTempMessage = [theTempMessage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"%2F"];
theTempMessage = [theTempMessage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"?" withString:@"%3F"];
theTempMessage = [theTempMessage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"%2C"];
theTempMessage = [theTempMessage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"%3D"];
theFinalMessage = [theTempMessage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"%26"];

NSString * stringToSend=theFinalMessage;
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:stringToSend];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL])

{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
}
```

Comment: why your are using the string replacement

Answer (score 10):

Add this to your Info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>whatsapp</string>
    </array>
```

Implement this code to the ViewController where you need to open WhatsApp for sharing. (like for example say a button action)
Update for swift 3 version (Xcode 8.x) : **Updated for deprecations**:

```
var str = "This is the string which you want to share to WhatsApp"
str=str.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: (NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed))!
let whatsappURL = URL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=\(str)")
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL) {
   UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
} else {
   showAlert(message: "Whatsapp is not installed on this device. Please install Whatsapp and try again.")
}
```

Here showAlert() is a custom function for showing an alert.

Comment: Since `openURL` was deprecated in iOS 10 You need to use `openURL` instead:

   `UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)`

Comment: Thanks :) nice share

Comment: Thanks for answer

Answer (score 1):

If you use "*[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];*" after string replcement it will open the safari browser not the whatsapp,

If you want to open whatsapp don't replace the string